# Scroll Bar Positioning

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a y-scrollable div, but the scroll bar be say... 200 px away from the div?

Like so:

[image: my drawing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not right-margin, that would add the space to the right of the scrollbar.

Use right-padding to give the box extra space to the right of the content.  Since this would be part of the box, the scrollbar would be to the right of that.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention...! is it possible to have this div a width of 100%, but the padding not be counted in the width?
In other words, have the div change size with the browser, BUT still keep the 200 px padding? without javascript

Comment: See my Fiddle (heh, that always sounds funny): http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/b6WVr/. I've amended it to do what you want using the box-sizing attribute. Support is pretty good (http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) but you can probably find a JS shim for older versions of IE.

Comment: It's supported in IE8+. If you need to support older versions, you'll have to resort to a nested div, or an IE-specific stylesheet that serves those browsers a different version. Worth adding that you'll need prefixed versions for now, along with the vanilla style: http://css-tricks.com/7323-box-sizing/ has the details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, give the box a `padding-right` of `200px`.